# What is this method?

Tags: javascript

```
rps=(a,b)=>a==b?'Draw!':`Player ${/rp|ps|sr/.test(a[0]+b[0])?2:1} won!`;
```

The function takes two players, and each of them can play "rock", "paper" or "scissors". If one of them wins, it is supposed to say per example "Player 1 won!".

I believe this is shortest way to do this game. I'm just trying to understand what is happening.

This is an arrow function and they are using a ternary operator as I can see and string literals. What I don't understand is this string interpolation `${/rp|ps|sr/.test(a[0]+b[0])?2:1}`

Could someone break it down for me? I'm trying to learn the fundamentals of JavaScript.

Comment: I guess what you're not familiar with is the _regex_, `/rp|ps|sr/` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: www.regular-expression.info has a good tutorial on regular expressions

Answer (score -1):

Regex `/rp|ps|sr/` (the pipe `|` is an `OR`) is tested against the 0th charvalue of a and b strings or the first element of each array if they are arrays concatenated using a nested ternary if it is not a draw

```
a==="r" and b==="p" => Player 2 won!
a==="p" and b==="s" => Player 2 won!
a==="s" and b==="r" => Player 2 won!
```

otherwise show "Player 1 won!"